# Cleanest way to make logging in Ruby Gem "library" be visible in Rails.logger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I know how to log in Rails through using Rails.logger. My question is, how to I make the methods of an object that has previously been externalized to a gem that is required by a Ruby on Rails application log appropriately, so that it can be seen in the standard Rails log when it needs to output something? Is there some way I can do it without requiring  Rails in its Gemfile?

For example, since the object code used to be part of a Rails application, we see the following:

```
if (val1 == val2)
      ## the converted strings are the same, log the differences (something was misparsed)
      ## for example, there can be mis-parsings between unit number and post-directionals
      logger.warn "Curious Address Mismatch (1) :: #{first}"  ##TODO: set these logging statements so that they log errors correctly when this method is called in a delayed job (which will be the case in Mintrak2)
      logger.warn "Curious Address Mismatch (2) :: #{second}"  

      return true
end
```

This logger used to be part of the Rails application, and so was conceivably a Rails.Logger. This no longer applies, and when the Gem need to debug, you see the error:

```
D, [2016-11-10T11:57:03.581467 #12602] DEBUG -- : Error importing FileSet: undefined local variable or method `logger' for AddressParser:Class
D, [2016-11-10T11:57:03.581660 #12602] DEBUG -- : BT: /var/www/mintrak2/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/ehs-address-parser-lib-f390aacab26a/lib/tlc_address_parser.rb:649:in `compare_address_hashes'
```

Should I just require Rails and move on? There is a CLI frontend to the library I'm using that can work without rails, so I don't want to bog down the library with Rails dependencies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make sure that Rails is loaded, then fully qualify the path to the logger, (i.e. `Rails.logger.warn`), or make a singleton that has a property which you can set from inside your Rails application. You could then use an initializer to dependency inject the reference to your Rails logger.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit on the second option? So far the library consists of a single class. Do I have to create another logger singleton class right next to it for this to work?

Comment: If you already have an existing logger singleton class, you can just literally do `JrKinnard::SomeGem::Logger.logger = Rails.logger` in an initializer, provided that `Logger` is a singleton with a `logger` attribute.